# Media player to add bookmarks at specific times in a video?

Tags: windows, media-player, bookmark

Is there a video player for Windows that lets you add bookmarks at specific times in the video?

For example I have a tutorial video that I frequently keep coming back to but only to look up a couple of things demonstrated at specific times, or a favorite movie or a tv show that I only watch for a favourite scene in it.

In both cases I'd love to be able to put a bookmark at a specific time in the video which I can jump to when I open the video in future.

This is like how you can link to youtube videos at specific times by adding `#MmSs` to the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.vlchelp.com/using-custom-bookmarks-vlc-media-player/) supports this feature.

You do it by clicking `Playback` → `Custom Bookmarks` (or, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) → `Create`, and VLC will create a bookmark at the current position (displayed in images below).

I've heard of some complains about it, but it's worth giving it a try.

How to do it (images):

[image]
[image]

To actually navigate to the bookmark, simply click on it from `Playback` → `Custom Bookmarks`.

Comment: I've edited your answer to show how to do this. If anything's wrong, feel free to change it. +1 for great option.

Comment: I tend to get a bit lazy on the tablet. It looks much better, indeed :). And it's correct.

Answer (score 5):

[KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/) is the perfect media player for this (and for everything else :).

I switched from VLC to this a year ago, because of the (simple) bookmark feature, and you can play *any* format of video.

To bookmark, 2 options:

1. right click > bookmark
2. press <kbd>p</kbd>

[image]

[image]

Features:

- free
- runs on Windows 2000 ([I think](http://www.kmplayer.com/features/features/14)) and over.
- can play any media format
- can add bookmarks easily

Comment: Another excellent answer. Since I experienced some non-related playback issues with VLC after the latest update, I'll deff. look into this myself.

Comment: @elderelder Thanks. It's a great program, I'm surprised it's free! No saying that VLC is bad - I thought it was the best before I discovered kmplayer.

Comment: I installed KMPlayer but it doesn't have a bookmark option for .mp4 extensions.