# A player or professional audio software to add comments with bookmarks at different specific times on audio files and embed them in files

Tags: bookmark, audio-player, embeddable

I have a lot of audio files including songs, podcasts, lecturers, and tutorial lessons, I need a simple player or even professional audio software to let me insert and add comments for important specific times that the speaker of a podcast talks and needs to be bookmarked and commented those times. for example; I have podcast audio with a duration time: of 60 min. From my point of view; there are 5 important points and things should be written a short comment in those different times (e.g, on 15:06 - 20:09 - 38:00 - 46:017 and 53:38) and also shown by signs as bookmarks in a tag or label forms for those audio files, so I could see those specific bookmarks (tag, label or whatever signs) to click on them, then open my comment as a pop-up menu forms or a separate small window to see, edit, add or delete my comments for those specific times that I think are important for me and should be bookmark and need comments. In this way, those bookmarks lead me to those times and I play from that time to listen and also see my comments and feedback.

**More important I need to embed those data inside in its audio files to avoid losing them by accident or any issues.**

I guess no simple and popular audio players on the market do this and my search was failed. I google it but didn't find software for that and a few online apps seem to do this for teamwork that is not suitable for my need, and I'm looking for personal use, not commercial on Windows 10 or 11.

A professional audio software would be fine if it creates what I described and I need, but a cheaper and lighter audio player is better than an expensive professional that needs more CPU and RAM memories. I tried some popular audio/video players, but they can't do this.

A similar question was asked [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11942/media-player-to-add-bookmarks-at-specific-times-in-a-video) about video files, and [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and [KMplayer](http://kmplayer.com/) were suggested, they do it incomplete and no embed of data inside the files, if software or OS crashed, formated, uninstalled, the whole bookmarks (data) will disappear and lose. They're temporary until you use them and if those players are removed from OS or reinstalled, the bookmark will be erased as well, and also they just do bookmarks for a specific time, not add comments.

Comment: I have created https://replayer.app, which is more suited for music rehearsals with cues, but it can hold cues with metadata for media files. You can store the metadata along with the media file(s) in a ZIP archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Audacity..

To add comment to the audio Edit->Metadata-> Add then add tag and value of this tag

To add comment/tag to specific part select this part, Edit->Labels->Add label at selection (or Ctrl-B)

Comment: Hi Romeo, I tried to add more than one comment in the "Edit Metadate" window and it adds more fields, but in exported mp3 file, just shows the default "comment" field in a player like AIMP, not the others. Also tried "Labels" on some parts of a file, but they could be used in Audacity itself. As far as I know so far; It can't embed those labels in exported mp3 or other audio formats to show on a player that supports show labels at specific times......

Comment: ....The labels need to open them in Audacity. The worse thing is; I can't save my labels, but in the Audacity project and in a test for a podcast with 60 min duration and 60 MB, it exported a project file with 1.5 GB!?
That's a huge size when it comes to thousand audio files in my archive; if I want to apply labels to every one of them. If I create labels for an audio file, I have to export it to a project file with a huge size, not a simple mp3 file. I guess Audacity and other sound editors like this are almost useless for the thing I need.

Comment: @MasoudMoghaddam, I think no software can do what you want outside own projects. And at the music players are to play music...

Comment: Maybe you are right, but currently, Audacity and even more professional sound editors just create comments, labels inside themselves, don't like to depend on them from A to Z, just need something to create, export data, then listen and see comments, labels in a light music player than to back to a sound editor for everything, even listening, especially with those huge project files. I guess someone or a team should start work on software for that. Many people like to have comments, labels, and more things for their audio tracks so that navigate better to important parts to find things easily.

Comment: @MasoudMoghaddam, if those comments are so important for you maybe you can change the format/player and take a look on karaoke format/players

Answer (score 1):

Transcribe! Is a windows and Linux app which allows that.
You can add marks at any point with a label.
Also it has a separate track in which you can add any text you want and drag it around
It stores all data in a file for each media alongside the original file.
It is paid with trial period.

Comment: I googled "Transcribe" and the following first result: "https://transcribe.wreally.com/". but this app converts audio to text and it's paid. I don't want to convert anything, just need to bookmark different times audio files, and write / insert text (comment, critic, feedback, etc) for each bookmark. Keep and embed those bookmarks and inserted texts inside audio files.

Comment: The software is Transcribe! , note the !

Comment: This is the website https://www.seventhstring.com/xscribe/screenshots.html

Comment: Thanks for the URL, I've tried the app, but it is like Audacity can create a label and it just uses itself and can't export an audio file with labels (in this case; my comments for the audio file) to use in a third-party player (it's a similar challenge in Audacity that I told in my comments to @Roemo). 
Audacity works better and smoother in this case than Transcribe as I tried both. I guess no regular audio player is showing this kind of label/bookmark out there that is created in an audio editor and it seems should use and see this label/bookmark in an audio editor.

Comment: I think you should be clearer with your ideal workflow. If you use audacity to add comments you can save the comments in the project. That is in its own folder and is independent of the os or app installation. You can backup those files also. The same applies with Transcribe! Which saves all in a single project file. You can use that apps as player. To embed the data in the audio file I see it difficult and not necessary. But if you insist you can create chapters in audacity, and put comment in chapter name. I don't know what is the max name size.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=FfHC12Xcjlk How To Add Chapters To Audio Books Using Audacity

Comment: As I said in my comment to @Romeo; saving to Audacity's project creates a huge file that is not a good option for a lot of audio files, but for a few files. (saved project for a 12 MB file, will create a 240 MB file. Now imagine thousands of audio files!).
Right now, I don’t consider I have a better option like Audacity or even Transcribe! And I expect I create those chapters/bookmarks so a player support and be able to show those chapters/bookmarks (with comments I inserted). without using the software I created those labels/comments.
.........

Comment: ........Currently, I think the best option for me is: 

1-  Open / import audio file in Audacity.
2-  Select a piece of track file, then choose Edit > Labels > Add Labels as Selection, then type to insert a label for that specific piece of track.
3-  Choose File > Export > Export Labels (saves a tiny .txt file of comments and duration of times to the same folder of the audio file).
Next time; open the audio file with Audacity, then choose File > Import to import the exported label file (.txt file).
.........

Comment: .....This process is easy, fast, and doesn’t need to deal with huge sizes of .project files. I guess it’s a good option, but not the best so far.